# How to access Jenkins dashboard locally when it is installed on staging server?

Tags: jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on Ubuntu staging server of my project (website) via putty as I am on WINDOWS7.
I started it and checked that it is running there. But when try to access http://staging.website.com:8080 it doesn't show the Jenkins dashboard.On asking with DEV team to give access like they have given access for port 3031 (staging.website.com:3031) they replied that is not possible because that port run by apache and we cant run port 8080 by apache.

So..how can I get access on this port...
Why I am doing this , because I want to automatically run my automation scripts at particular time without my laptop up and on all the time.

I am on Windows7 and have java to write by scripts using Maven,webdriver,testng.
Please suggest a way to solve this.

Comment: Why don't change to a different port and try?  `java - jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8082` for instance.

Comment: I fail to fully understand your configuration. Is port 8080 currently used by apache ? If so what port are using you using to start jenkins ? If you want to start jenkins on port 3031, use -httpPort=3031 on the command line (cf @Raghuram's comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Raghuram and coffeebreaks,
I used this tutorial to set it up on port 3033 its up and running 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu