# Jenkins Page Not Loading. Apache2 Ubuntu Page Starts Up Instead

Tags: maven, jenkins, devops

I'm new to DevOps and build/automation tools. I installed Apache Maven and Jenkins, but the Jenkins dashboard is not popping up. In other words, I should be seeing this:

[image]

But I'm instead seeing this:

[image]

I found a similar question here, but I was unable to understand what to do: [How to access Jenkins dashboard locally when it is installed on staging server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460103/how-to-access-jenkins-dashboard-locally-when-it-is-installed-on-staging-server)

From what I understand, I need to make Jenkins open up on a different port, but I'm not sure how to do this. I checked in services and I can confirm that Jenkins is in fact running.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but this is off-topic, it has nothing to do with software development. Probably it should be moved to superuser.

Comment: To say that it has "nothing" to do with software development is ignorant. While it might not be directly involved in the nitty gritty of producing software, it's quite an essential part of developing successful software solutions, but you are entitled to your opinion. There are several troubleshooting related posts relating to Jenkins (such as mine) on Stack. Perhaps you should visit those as well and let people know how you feel.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out, but I still don't understand what that Apache page is. For anyone wondering how to fix the issue with the dashboard not popping up:

STEP 1: I was exploring the installation directory and found a file called jenkins.xml with the line --httpPort=8080.

STEP 2: It wouldn't let me edit and save the file so I dragged it to my desktop where it let me make changes. I changed 8080 to 8082, saved, and then placed the file back in the installation directory.

STEP 3: I didn't notice any changes until I restarted the Jenkins service and it's showing the dashboard now.

I still would like to know what that "Apache 2 Ubuntu Default Page" is about.